# How can I create a fallback rule in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider this makefile:

```
default: c

a:: b
    touch a

a:: b
    ls -lt a b
    touch a

c: a
    touch c
```

Output is this:

```
$ touch b
$ make
touch a
ls -lt a b
-rw-r--r-- 1 tkcook tkcook 0 Apr  1 11:32 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 tkcook tkcook 0 Apr  1 11:31 b
touch a
touch c
```

I understand that double-colon rules permit multiple rules to be executed for the same target, but they do still all depend on prerequisites being newer than the target to trigger.  In this case, therefore, I expected that `a` being newer than `b` after execution of the first rule would prevent the second rule's recipe from being run, but instead, both rules for making `a` are executed.

Ultimately, I am trying to handle a situation where there are two possible ways of making a target. One is very cheap but doesn't always work, whereas the other is very expensive but always works.  When the target is out of date, I'd basically like to try the first method first,  and then fall back to the second (only) if the first fails.  Given that double-colon rules don't seem to be achieving that, what can I do instead?

Comment: The documentation does not clearly specify, but your experiment seems to show that `make` performs some kind of direct or indirect timestamp caching.  I'm not sure what exactly you're asking us, then, since you seem to have answered your own question.  FWIW, I do note that yours is not among the use cases contemplated by the documentation.

Comment: Well, I think the last part of the question indicates what I'm trying to achieve.  If, for whatever reason, the `touch` in the first recipe for `a` fails, the second recipe should run but otherwise only the first recipe should run.

Answer (score 2):

> Why are both rules for making a executed, even though the first one makes a newer than b?

Keep in mind that *while executing recipes* `make` only checks for the exit codes. It **never** cares if the target files were even created, not even mentioning their timestamps.

What the (explicit) double-colon rules are designed for is to choose the recipe(s) based on which prerequisites have changed. That means they are always independent of one another.

> I'd basically like to try the first method and if that doesn't work do the other one instead, but both methods get executed.

Use single recipe with "or-ed" commands like `./script1 || ./script2`